# How to use List.Distinct to populate a custom class?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, class

I have the following two classes (in C#)

```
public class courseList 
{
            public string MajorName { get; set; }
            public string MajorNameID { get; set; }
            public string CourseID { get; set; }
            public string CourseName { get; set; }
}

public class CourceNames
{
        [DataMember]
        public string CourseID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
}

public class Courses
{
        [DataMember]
        public string MajorNameID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MajorName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<CourceNames> CourseNames { get; set; }

        public Courses()
        {
            Course = new List<CourceNames>();
        }
}
```

I am reading two tables from MYSQL database using SQLreader to

> `List<courseList> courseList`

class.
MY result record is as follows :

```
MajorNameID   MajorName     CourseName         CourseID
100000        Physics       Thermodynamic      PHY101
100000        Physics       Quantum            PHY200
100000        Physics       Relativity         PHY300
200000        Chemistry     Gases              CHM300
200000        Chemistry     Oreganic           CHM500
200000        Chemistry     Inroganic          CHM120
300000        Mathematics   Pure               MAT100
300000        Mathematics   Applied            MAT300
```

As u could see, I want to populate Courses class. I am not sure how I could do this using Linq.

I recently learnt the following method but it's not working correctly.

```
        List<Courses> courses = courseList .GroupBy(
            d => new { d.MajorNameID , d.MajorName },
        d => d.MajorName,
        (key, g) => new courses 
        {
            MajorNameID  = key.MajorNameID,
            MajorName  = key.MajorName,
            CourseNames = g.Distinct().ToList()
        }
        ).ToList();
```

I get the following error :

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CourceNames>'...........
```

I do not fully understand the above. Could someone help me how I could set it up correctly?
I want to load couses per each major in the list.

Comment: `List<CourseNames> a = new List<string>();` - do you understand why this won't work? That's what the error message states that you're triyng to do.

Comment: Yes, but how I set to coursenames ? Myclass is not atring list.

Comment: What's your expected result? I don't think `Courses` collection can carry your result set from db

Comment: I updated courseList class where SQLdatareader loads the data. I want to avoid repetition of MajowName and MajorNameID by using List<Courses>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplifying your group by to just grouping by key and using `Select` expression on each item in group.

This final trick is that you have to cast the course names to the correct type. The compiler should give you enough hints, but Linq GroupBy is VERY different to MySQL/TSQL GroupBy statements so they can be tricky to master at first.

```
List<Courses> courses = courseList.GroupBy(
    d => new { d.MajorNameID, d.MajorName }
    ).Select(g => new Courses
    {
        MajorNameID = g.Key.MajorNameID,
        MajorName = g.Key.MajorName,
        CourseNames = g.Distinct().Select(c => 
            new CourceNames { CourseID = c.CourseID, CourseName = c.CourseName }).ToList()
    }
).ToList();
```

[UPDATE: I don't normally use element projection syntax, so I had to compile this to check]
Using the same `GroupBy` overload as your question (element projection), this is the same query, note that the element selector expression now selects the elements, the original post has a key expression in there instead:

```
List<Courses> courses2 = courseList.GroupBy(
    d => new { d.MajorNameID, d.MajorName }, // key selector
    c => new CourceNames { CourseID = c.CourseID, CourseName = c.CourseName }, // element selector
    (key, g) => new Courses
    {
        MajorNameID = key.MajorNameID,
        MajorName = key.MajorName,
        CourseNames = g.Distinct().ToList()
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The lambda variable `g` is a group, you cannot directly do a `.Distinct` on it**

```
List<Courses> courses = courseList .GroupBy(
        d => new { d.MajorNameID , d.MajorName },
        d => d.MajorName,
        (key, g) => new Courses 
        {
            MajorNameID  = key.MajorNameID,
            MajorName  = key.MajorName,
            CourseNames = g.Distinct().ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

---

**You need to project the course name from the group `g` and then do a `.Distinct` on it. Which will be like:**

```
List<Courses> courses = courseList .GroupBy(
        d => new { d.MajorNameID , d.MajorName },
        d => d.MajorName,
        (key, g) => new Courses 
        {
            MajorNameID  = key.MajorNameID,
            MajorName  = key.MajorName,
            CourseNames = g.Select(x => x.CourseName).Distinct().ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is "(key, g) => new courses "  be "(key, g) => new Courses " ? Also I can not see "x.CourseName". Is that right ?

Comment: @PCG fixed that are you now able to access the `.CourseName` property ?

Comment: I will test it.